# Removing special characters and replacing with relevant text based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp

When I Run OCR on certain docs prefixes of dates are getting replaced by # or any Special character.
as a result, my NER is taking month and year but not considering the date number.

I have tried pyspellchecker, gingerit, and other spelling correct libraries but nothing helped

eg:
    1. 15% March 2019
    2. 3" oct 2020

I want to replace the special characters in my OCR output based on two conditions:

```
1. Its starts with a number  
2. Its followed by a month
```

Required output:

```
1. 15th March 2019  
2. 3rd oct 2020
```

Can you please help me with python code for the same.

I tried Regex but got stuck in adding the month condition to it.

code:

```py
r = re.compile(r"(?:^|\s)([0-9?])(\w+)")
items = r.findall(f)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

text = "on 13# november 1990 we sign the deal"
for word in text.split():
    if word.startswith("0" or '1' or '3') or word.endswith("#"):
        print (word)
```

Comment: Hi, please share some code.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0):

This `Regex` phrase can be a good starting point:

```
([12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9]).\s+\w+\s+[12][0-9]{3}
```

Explanation:

- `([12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])` - represent days in month (1-31)
- `[12][0-9]{3}` - represent year (1000-2999)
- `.` - exactly one of any char
- `\s+\w+\s+` - one or more of whitespaces before and after a full word